# Implement MongoDB Data Listener for swift

Tags: swift, database, mongodb, listener

I am building a chat app in Swift, using MongoDB. How can I implement a data listener so that new messages automatically show up in the app?

Comment: could you provide some more details about the current state of your app and the approach you've taken so far?

Comment: It's a simple messaging app that I'm doing for a personal project, and so far I have gotten the uploading of messages to work. So when I click send, the message will send but now I need to implement a data listener such that when it recognizes the messages have changed, it will refresh the chat page to display the new messages. I just need a little help in the right direction.

Comment: when you click send where is your message going? How is it getting to the DB?

Comment: I do a POST to Mongo, and save it in a collection there.